# Como trocar o tema do dashboard nebular NGX-Admin?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html5, aplicação-web

Olá,
 gostaria de saber se tem como trocar o tema e a cor do dashboard nebular NGX-Admin?
Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

`theme.modules.ts`, no bloco:

```
const NB_THEME_PROVIDERS = [
...NbThemeModule.forRoot(
   {
      name: '**default | cosmic**',
   },
   [DEFAULT_THEME, COSMIC_THEME],
).providers,
...NbSidebarModule.forRoot().providers,
...NbMenuModule.forRoot().providers,
];
```